# Redcarpet Syntax Highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, redcarpet

I'm trying to get Syntax Highlighting with [Redcarpet](https://github.com/Theminijohn/redcarpet) working

My `appliaction_helper.rb`:

````
module ApplicationHelper

  def markdown(text)
    render_options = {
        # will remove from the output HTML tags inputted by user
        filter_html:     true,
        # will insert <br /> tags in paragraphs where are newlines
        hard_wrap:       true,
        # hash for extra link options, for example 'nofollow'
        link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow' },
        # Prettify
        prettify:        true
    }
    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(render_options)

    extensions = {
        #will parse links without need of enclosing them
        autolink:           true,
        # blocks delimited with 3 ` or ~ will be considered as code block.
        # No need to indent.  You can provide language name too.
        # ```ruby
        # block of code
        # ```
        fenced_code_blocks: true,
        # will ignore standard require for empty lines surrounding HTML blocks
        lax_spacing:        true,
        # will not generate emphasis inside of words, for example no_emph_no
        no_intra_emphasis:  true,
        # will parse strikethrough from ~~, for example: ~~bad~~
        strikethrough:      true,
        # will parse superscript after ^, you can wrap superscript in ()
        superscript:        true
        # will require a space after # in defining headers
        # space_after_headers: true
    }
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions).render(text).html_safe
  end

end
````

Although the output is displayed in a codeblock (redcarpet):

[image]

I can't find the `Syntax Highlighting`.

I just got into Redcarpet, someone know a solution for this?

Comment: I will suggest you to colorize code on client side. It is much easier.

Comment: Are they any gems or Tutorials that you know ?

Comment: I use [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/). It is rather simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok i found -> [Markdown and code syntax highlighting in Ruby on Rails (using RedCarpet and CodeRay)](http://allfuzzy.tumblr.com/post/27314404412/markdown-and-code-syntax-highlighting-in-ruby-on-rails) which pretty much worked (together with some custom css for Coderay).

Gemfile:

```
gem 'redcarpet', github: 'vmg/redcarpet'
gem 'coderay'
```

Application_helper.rb

```
class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, language)
    CodeRay.scan(code, language).div
  end
end

def markdown(text)
  coderayified = CodeRayify.new(:filter_html => true, 
                                :hard_wrap => true)
  options = {
    :fenced_code_blocks => true,
    :no_intra_emphasis => true,
    :autolink => true,
    :strikethrough => true,
    :lax_html_blocks => true,
    :superscript => true
  }
  markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified, options)
  markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
end
```

Comment: `def block_code(code, language)
    language ||= :plaintext
    CodeRay.scan(code, language).div
  end`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick way to do it with [Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge#you-can-even-use-it-with-redcarpet):

```
require 'redcarpet'
require 'rouge'
require 'rouge/plugins/redcarpet'

class HTML < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include Rouge::Plugins::Redcarpet # yep, that's it.
end
```

Of course this requires `rouge` to be in your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `Redcarpet` can do that. In my project I followed the Railscasts episode about `Redcarpet` which also tackles syntax highlighting. It makes use of [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) and [Albino](https://github.com/github/albino).

Link to the ASCIIcast version is [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet).

Comment: Indeed, Redcarpet is *just* a Markdown parser. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I followed the Railscast (which is pretty updated). Basically i can't implement Pygments/Albino with redcarpet.

Comment: You have to install pygments first with `pip install Pygments`. If you don't have python on your machine, you should download python first, since pip is python's package manager.

Comment: If you install both Ruby and Python on your server, then yes.

Comment: Ok, Well i'm searching for just a Syntax Highlighter implementation like CodeRayify :)

Comment: Well use Coderay then! It's a lot simpeler to use and doesn't rely on Python.

Comment: Just found the solution. Thanks anyway